# App displaying different text sizes in two phones of the same model

Tags: android, text, size

I'm having a weird problem in my app.
An user sent me as feedback a screenshot of the app's checkout screen. His phone is a Galaxy S3 (i9300). This is the screenshot:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/gqek.png/

As you can see, it's all messed up because of the EditText and TextView text sizes.
So I got my friend's Galaxy S3 (SGH-i747) to test the app, and for my surprise, it was absolutely normal:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/wt68.png/

What could be hapenning here? I checked with them and they didn't change any dpi settings, their phones aren't even rooted. Maybe it's something related to their Android version?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out what was causing this problem.
In Galaxy phones (I don't know about other Android models), you can change the font size in the Settings Menu. The user that was having the problem had the font set to Large, and since my TextViews' textSize were set using "sp", it would enlarge them. All I had to do was to use "dp" instead of "sp", so they won't change according to the phone's font size.